# How to reference not the Outer query, but Outer Outer query in Django ORM?

Tags: subquery, django-orm

I have this code:

#models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Request(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    refugee = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, related_name="requests", verbose_name="refugees")

class Chat(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="chat_users_added_to")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=ChatTypesChoices.choices)
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, models.CASCADE, related_name="chat_messages")
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
```

#views.py

```
queryset = User.objects.all()
unread_messages = ChatMessage.objects.filter(
    chat__request_id__in=Subquery(
        Request.objects.filter(
            refugee=OuterRef('pk')  # here is the PROBLEM -- I need to reference not ChatMessagePk but UserPk
        ).values('id')
    )
).values('chat__request').annotate(message_count=Count('id'))

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    unread_messages=Coalesce(Subquery(unread_messages), 0)
)
```

This code attempts to count all messages related to all chats related to all requests related to the current user in the queryset row.
I have chosen this approach, however I can't find a way to reference the User object, but not ChatMessage objects in the following line of code

```
refugee=OuterRef('pk')
```

I know that it is possible using SQL, but how to achieve this kind of behaviour in Django ORM?

I also tried use ArrayAggregation for this purpose

```
queryset = User.objects.all()

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    request_ids=ArrayAgg("requests__id")
)

unread_messages = Request.objects.filter(
    pk__in=OuterRef("request_ids")
)

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    unread_messages=Coalesce(Subquery(unread_messages), 0)
)
```

to achieve something like this in SQL:

```
WITH user_requests AS (
    SELECT
       uchat_user.username,
       Array_Agg(uchat_request.id) AS request_ids
    FROM uchat_user
    LEFT JOIN uchat_request ON uchat_request.refugee_id = uchat_user.id
    GROUP BY uchat_user.username
)

SELECT 
    *,
    (
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchat_request WHERE uchat_request.id IN (SELECT unnest(user_requests.request_ids))
    ) AS total_requests
FROM user_requests
```

but it shows this error:

```
operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
LINE 1: ...efugee_id" FROM "uchat_request" U0 HAVING U0."id" IN (ARRAY_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```